# Kentico : Unable to upload image using quick insert

Tags: image-upload, kentico

I was trying to insert image on a blog post document using quick insert image in Kentico's WYSIWG editor.

But during upload process it seems to stall.

On further debug I find that the button event `btnHidden_Click` was not called within the usercontrol

> \CMSModules\Content\Controls\Attachments\DirectFileUploader\DirectFileUploaderControl.ascx.cs.

There are some silver-light error messages as well

```
Line: 231
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2108    
Category: InitializeError       
Message: Failed to download the splash screen
```

Comment: Which browser do you use? Chrome, I guess...

Comment: Do you have any external sliverlight objects in the page?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Kentico are you using but if it's version 7 or older try to add the following key into your web.config file:

```
<add key="CMSUseSilverlightUploader" value="false" />
```